# What's the best way to share an instance of an object across many objects?

Tags: c#, wpf

## Intro

I want an instance of a parser to be passed to an object and all of its children, they may also have children. What's the best way to pass the parser without each object containing another instance of it?

## In Depth

Let's say I have:

- An object called `CustomControl`, which contains a `UIElementCollection` property,
- Other objects which are derived from `CustomControl`, therefore having their own collections
- Another object called `Parser` which will implement `IParser`

The `Parser` will contain a method: `public static CustomControl[] Parse(string s)`.

I want to pass the parser class to each `CustomControl` derived object and all of their children which are also derived from `CustomControl`. These children may have their own children.

I will allow the user to change the parser to another object which implements `IParser`.

Comment: If the method is `static` there is no need to pass an instance around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just pass the parser reference directly to the children.

When you assign an object to a variable (including a field or parameter), you are only assigning a reference to that object, and you are never making a copy, unless the object is a of a value type, like an `int` or `DateTime`.

If you don't want the children to contain a field each to refer to the parser, you can assign a parser reference to a static member somewhere and then the children can just get the parser from that static member.

Comment: I'm assuming it will be possible to modify the static property, right? In other words to change the parser to another class.

Comment: Yes, you can change the reference to another parser and then any child objects that access the static member will get the new reference to the other parser.